# I am looking for a site similar to 'Django Admin' that works with a No-sql database such as ArangoDB

Tags: django, django-admin, arangodb, pyarango, nosql

This is a fairly advanced question, but looking for help here.

My goal is how to get a generic object manager site (like django-admin) working for ArangoDB and I'm looking for a good answer on how to achieve that.

I absolutely love the Django-Admin website. But I am using a NoSQL database and this currently doesn't seem supported. I am using ArangoDB, but I guess this question would be applicable to other NoSQL databases as well such as Mongo or CouchDB although I'm not using them.

This could happen one of two ways:
1) Is there a way to write some data adapter that sits inbetween django-admin and the arrangodb nosql database that allows this to work? I have some knowledge of QuerySets and Managers. Maybe one could re-write one to support ArrangoDB? But these do seem very specific and tied heavily to SQL.

2) Is there a another generic object admin django app that works well with nosql databases? It would need to be similar to django-admin and it would have to be able to add/update/delete objects.

For what it's worth, I'm aware of 'django-nonrel' but they don't support ArrangoDB, and the site seems to have almost no recent activity and the codebase does not seem very official. I don't find this a very appealing solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django with NoSQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41406219/django-with-nosql-database)

Comment: Not a duplicate. I'm not looking for Django with NoSQL as I've already got that running, but rather Django-Admin (i.e. the generic entity editor admin site). I am looking for ways to either build my own Manager class, or a replacement for django-admin (a django app).